# TP4056 Output Voltage Problem

Tags: voltage, batteries, charger, tp4056

I have charger circuit TP4056 based.
My problem: Output voltage of TP4056 is very variable.
Input voltage of TP4056 is about 5.4VDC from DC power supply.
Output voltage is between 4.0V and 5.4. I changed input and output capacitor. The problem still persists.

I share charger circuit of PCB. Also i share ossiloscope printing screen of output.Please help me :)

Notes:  Only the charging circuit part is assembled.Other component disassembled.
In the problem I mentioned above, the battery is not mounted. I know that battery is not required for 4.2V output voltage according  to datasheet.I bought TP4056 from LCSC.

tp4056 link: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Battery-Management-ICs_TPOWER-TP4056_C382139.html

[image: my charger circuit]

[[image: TP4056/ VDD-VBAT output printing screen2]

Comment: Probably too low current. Have you tried with a battery?

Comment: I didnt try. But I have tried. Max output voltage 4.320, Min output voltage 4.080V.
Performance improved but not enough acc. to datasheet. Why do I have to connect a battery? Can't I use this IC as a regulator without a battery? Unfortunately TP4056 datasheet is not good :( @winny

Comment: Probably not. Get an LDO if that’s what you want.